# Selenium ".text" not returning hyphen values

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape data on gambling odds from an aggregating website. Sometimes, the sportsbook source on the website doesn't have odds for a specific game, and so the aggregating website displays a dash or hyphen ("-"). My scraper returns this hyphen value as empty, and that screws up my for loop.

When I scrape through, my code works fine if the odds exist. When the odds don't exist and the site displays a "-" the response is empty. I've tried using `.text` and `.get_attribute("innerText")` and I can't find any other methods that would return text.

This is the element that works:

```
<section class="_2NFWr" data-vertical-sbid="279" style="">
    <main class="_2ZO4X">
        <div class="_3h0tU _3ptK- _1qU_1">
            <span class="_3YgRM _1QEDd">
                <span class="">+145</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="_3h0tU _3ptK- _1qU_1 _1YNCg">
            <span class="_3YgRM _1QEDd">
                <span class="">-155</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </main>
</section>
```

My code:

```
away_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('div._3h0tU._3ptK-._1qU_1')
away_odds = away_odds.text

home_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('div._3h0tU._3ptK-._1qU_1._1YNCg')
home_odds = home_odds.text

print "Away Odds: "+ away_odds
print "Home Odds: "+ home_odds
```

Returns:

```
Away Odds: +145
Home Odds: -155
```

This is the section that doesn't work

```
    <section class="_2NFWr" data-vertical-sbid="1602" style="">
        <main class="_2ZO4X">
            <div class="_3h0tU _3ptK-">
                <span class="_3YgRM _1QEDd">
                    <span class="">-</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="_3h0tU _3ptK- _1YNCg">
                <span class="_3YgRM _1QEDd">
                    <span class="">-</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </main>
    </section>
```

My code is the same, and the response is empty. This breaks a while loop that I'm using to interact with the page, and stops it prematurely.

I've also tried the following:

Scraping from the nested class

```
away_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('div._3h0tU._3ptK-._1qU_1')
away_odds = away_odds.find_element_by_css_selector('span._3YgRM._1QEDd')
away_odds = away_odds.text

home_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('div._3h0tU._3ptK-._1qU_1._1YNCg')
home_odds = home_odds.find_element_by_css_selector('span._3YgRM._1QEDd')
home_odds = home_odds.text
```

and using the `Inner Text` attribute

```
away_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('div._3h0tU._3ptK-._1qU_1')
away_odds = away_odds.get_attribute('innerText')

home_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('div._3h0tU._3ptK-._1qU_1._1YNCg')
home_odds = home_odds.get_attribute('innerText')
```

In both instances, I still get an empty value from the "-" in the tags

I expect the code to output the text value "-"

Comment: In your second example, the `div` doesn't have the same classes as the `div` in the first one..

Comment: Yes, as @IsmaelPadilla pointed the class name does not match with the one specified in xpath. Probably you might have got `NoSuchElementException` and kicked out off the execution.

Comment: @supputuri *facepalm* That's correct. I am going to double check the structure and solve this problem on my side. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`away_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('div._3h0tU._3ptK-._1qU_1')`
is different from

`away_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('_3h0tU _3ptK- _1YNCg')`

and

`away_odds = odds_element.find_element_by_css_selector('_3YgRM _1QEDd')`

my advice is that you first analyze the pattern in the website and then get the values.

for example, do this

```
parent_list=driver.find_elements_by_class('name of main class')
child1=parent_list[0].find_elements_by_class('name of inner class')
grand_child= ____same thing follows___
```

use the `find_elements_by` wisely. You can use XPath and CSS Selector in the worst dynamic environments.

Comment: Right- I wasn't clear in the question that I know they are different. One is Away and one is Home. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I tried to get the text value from the inner element as well, and I got the same results - no value returned on the hyphenated values.

Comment: values are nested. You'll have to nest the for loops.

Comment: That makes sense, and I do nest "games > odds > individual sportsbook odds". The individual sportsbook odds is what this example is about, and I want to separate home and away into separate dictionaries. Are you saying I need to nest another loop inside of the individual sportsbook odds loop? There's only one element each that I'm interested in for home and away, so I'm not sure that a loop would help. Beyond that, this doesn't explain why the example I added to the question doesn't work. I'm looking at the individual element as close to the text as possible and getting nothing back.

Comment: I'm now reading this with fresher eyes, and you're correct. the elements are different. I'm not sure that the looping you're suggesting is the right solution, but I can now go back to my code knowing more than I did before. Thank you!

Comment: What you can do is to just analyze the classes manually. I think that there will be a pattern which separates the home and away classes (or id,name). What you need to do is to go to the deepest until you have 2 choices. Use If/Else inside a loop. If the element has a class name that matches your even/odd class, just fetch that element of let it be.

Comment: do this- ```x=br.find_elements_by_class('_3YgRM _1QEDd')``` and after that, ```y=x.br.find_element_by_tag('span').text``` print(x). see if it works. And if there is problem of the breaking loop, use ```try: throw:except```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the odds are wrapped in `<span class="_3YgRM _1QEDd">` elements.  You could use `find_elements_by_css_selector` to get a list.

For example (assuming the HTML above is in `your_local.html` :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file:///C:/your_local.html")

away_odds = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span._3YgRM._1QEDd')

for element in away_odds:
    print(element.text)

#=> +145
#=> -155
#=> -
#=> -
```

Comment: I just tried this outside of the context of my for loops, and I did get hyphenated values. But when I tried using the `span._3YgRM._1QEDd` css selector in my for loop, I got nothing. For reference, I'm looping over each individual game listed on the page, and then each individual odds element (including home and away) to create home and away dictionaries for each game. I understand that this is a simple representation of the data structure that I need, but I don't understand why it doesn't work in my for loops.

Comment: Can you provide the full html for the section of the page under-test?  Without that, it's guesswork...